# How to retrieve currency symbol from database using php?

Tags: php, html-entities, currency-formatting

I have a customer database and i m retrieving customer's company name from one of the tables (cache_cust).I am saving 'company_name' in this format e.g Mr €2 , Mr €1 , £ land etc.
These currency symbols are saving correctly in the database.BUT when i try to retrieve the 'company_name' values they show me characters like this:

```
For example : for "  Mr €2 " ,it shows " Mr â‚¬2   "  .
```

How can i display my data on the php page as it is saved in the database?How can i avoid these kind of symbols appearing on my web page?PLEASE note that these values are coming from the database.I have tried htmlspecialcharacters and htmlentities but they didn't work.Please help.Thanks

AN UPDATE:
When i try to post the 'company_name' text box value to next page and try to retrieve it using print($_POST['company_name]); ,it Still DOESN'T display the symbols and doesn't include special characters.

Comment: your page encoding needs to be UTF-8.

Comment: @djjjuk.Thanks.But how can i check or set my page encoding to UTF-8 to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

how is your page rendered - in PHP? if so, try putting the content type as UTF-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Thanks.Already set as: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Answer (score 0):

What is the character set / collation for the `company_name` field?

It sounds like you have the default character set `latin1`. You will need to set it to UTF-8 `utf8_unicode_ci` if this is the case.

Also be aware if the column isn't UTF8 - any special characters you have already saved into it will need to re-saving since they will have been converted from their multi-byte form into single-byte representation. You can use [this chart](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) to perform string replacements if you are in that situation.

Comment: @Dab J.Thanks But the problem is not in the database.The problem is with my php web page which is showing symbols incorrectly.The values in the database are stored correctly.But don't appear correctly on my WEB PAGE.Ta

Comment: Apologies - missed that bit - have you tried executing `SET NAMES utf8` before selecting company information?

Comment: @Dab J.Yes.i have set it in my meta tag.<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: No I mean run the SQL statement `SET NAMES utf8` - as in - `$query = 'SET NAMES utf8';` Before you make any `SELECT` statements